# Convert GIF to PDF byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am calling a third-party webservice which returns a GIF. I want to convert that image to a PDF, which I then want to convert into `byte[]`.

Here's my code:

```
 HttpWebRequest NxtserviceRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ImgPath);
 NxtserviceRequest.Method = "GET";
 HttpWebResponse NxtServiceResponse = (HttpWebResponse)NxtserviceRequest.GetResponse();

 Stream NxtresponseStream;
 NxtresponseStream = NxtServiceResponse.GetResponseStream();

 using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
 {
      int count = 0;
      do
      {
           byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
           count = NxtresponseStream.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
           ms.Write(buf, 0, count);
      } while (NxtresponseStream.CanRead && count > 0);

      binaryData = ms.ToArray();
      ...
 }
```

When I am trying to pass this `binaryData` on file browser, it's showing error on PDF generate.

Comment: You're writing a stream of which you know is a GIF file and return it to a file browser and expect it would be a PDF file? You will probably need a converter for this, something like http://www.rasteredge.com/software/gif-pdf-converter/

Comment: Another option could be to use [itextsharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/) to create a pdf document and embed the image.